# Multiple YouTube channels under a single account

Tags: youtube

On some places, I found that it is now possible to create multiple YouTube channels under a single account. Upon going to http://www.youtube.com/channel_switcher, there should be a button - `Create A New Channel` or something similar - but in my case,  I don't have this button on this page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, I must click on "Switch account" first. Then I get option to add account.
You can see how to do it on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5qOSRzFzU8